# Can't instal 12.04, stops at purple screen

Tags: 12.04, screen

I tried to install 12.04 with a CD. I downloaded everything, burned the CD and changed the boot order from my PC.

I then restart my PC with the CD in it but all I get is a purple screen with a keyboard and a menu at the bottom of the screen and it blocks there. I read that you are supposed to push a random keyboard button but when I do it, nothing happens except for one time where I got to another screen with a bunch of language but then it stops there.

Hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Try the [Alternate CD](http://mirror01.th.ifl.net/releases/12.04/ubuntu-12.04-alternate-i386.iso)

Answer (score 1):

The random key is the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on the keyboard. Once you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, Select your language and press <kbd>Esc</kbd> on the keyboard. Then choose one of the following options:

1. Try Ubuntu without installing
2. Install Ubuntu
3. Check disc for defects
4. Test memory
5. Boot from first hard disk

If you still can not get in, it could be that your Graphics card is too new for Ubuntu to recognize the drivers to work. I would suggest that you go and unplug your graphics card from your computer and use the on-board graphics card until after you have installed Ubuntu. Before the install, Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and then hit <kbd>F6</kbd>. Select `nomodeset` and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then choose what you want to do. Continue with your installation. When the installation is done, Install all of the latest updates, then turn off your computer and put back the graphics card. Then install the drivers(Ubuntu might recognize the card and prompt you to install the driver. After that, hope for the best.

Happy installation

Comment: I tried it but not even the enter key worked :/ And my computer is 64bit

Comment: Do you have a graphics card installed on your computer? If so, which one?

Comment: Yeah,quite a powerful one too :p It's the Radeon Hd 7970...

Comment: Do you have a on-board graphics card.

Comment: Yeah that too.....

Comment: I believe that you are having a problem with the graphics card not working(probably because it is new and power full). Could you remove your graphics card just for the installation). If you do decide to remove your graphics card, when you hit the purple screen, Press Enter,then F6<, then select `nomodeset`, and press Enter. Then just chose what you want to do. Good luck.

Comment: Ok thanks,I will do that :D
The problem with the grapphics card iq only for the installation?Because if It is also when Ubuntu is installed....

Comment: I don't think that the drivers are installed during installation. On the note of installation, set your computer to require a password to login in the install. you can change that setting later. After installation of Ubuntu and the updates, shut down your computer, and install your card. when you restart, Ubuntu might recognize it and prompt you to install the drivers. One warning. After you install your drivers and reboot, either you will have beautiful graphics, or later when you login, your graphics will be corrupted. We will cross that line when we get there.

Comment: Ok,Thank you very much
I will do it tomorrow when I have the time

Comment: Your welcome. I added everything that I told you in the last few comments into my answer.